# Page allowed to public in asp.net FormAuthentication is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-authentication

I am using FormAuthenticaion in my asp.net project but cannot grant access to a specific page. I have tried all the answers available on internet but none of them is working. here is my code

Web.Config

```
     <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>

    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms name="PIMAutontication" loginUrl="/User/login.aspx"  ></forms>

    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

     <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/404.html"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/404.html"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/404.html"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>

  <location path="~/Test/Test.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                    {
                        FormsIdentity id =
                            (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                        // Get the stored user-data, in this case, our roles
                        string userData = ticket.UserData;
                        string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean it just redirects me to login page